Quadratic functions between two-dimensional vector spaces (over $\mathbb R$)
I am to define the notion of a function $F:V \to W$ being quadratic using coordinate systems, show that this definition is independent of the choice of coordinates. Next, I must show that if, for any $l \in W^*$ and $\textbf u, \textbf v \in V$, there are constants $a, b, c$ such that for all $t \in \mathbb R$, $Q:V \to W$ satisfies $l(Q(t \textbf u+ \textbf v))=at^2+bt+c$ $(\dagger)$, then $Q$ is quadratic.
Let $\langle \textbf v_1, \textbf v_2 \rangle$, $\langle \textbf w_1, \textbf w_2 \rangle$ be bases for $V$ and $W$, and $\langle \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \rangle$, $\langle \mu_1, \mu_2 \rangle$ their respective duals. I defined $F$ to be quadratic iff $F$ is of the form $L_1 \textbf w_1 + L_2 \textbf w_2$, where $L_i$ is a linear combination of $\lambda_1^2, \lambda_1 \lambda_2, \lambda_2^2$ $(i = 1, 2)$. It is clear that this definition is independent of the choice of bases.
I'm stuck on the second part, which I believe is about a coordinate-free characterization of quadraticity. It is clear to me that all quadratics satisfy $(\dagger)$, so I am somewhat confident in the definition I've made. Assuming I have the right definition, considering the expression $(\mu_i \circ F)(v) = \mu_i (F(x_1 \textbf v_1+x_2 \textbf v_2))$ must be promising.
The expression $(\mu_i \circ F)(v)$ determines functions $a_m, b_m, c_m$ in $$\mu_i(F(x_1 \textbf v_1+x_2 \textbf v_2))$$ $$= a_1(x_2)x_1^2 + b_1(x_2)x_1 + c_1(x_2) = a_2(x_1)x_2^2 + b_2(x_1)x_2 + c_2(x_1).$$ Setting $x_i = 0$ determines $c_i$ as a quadratic function in $x_j$. I don't know how to proceed from here.
I would appreciate any help, thanks!

You want to show that $F$ is of the form $L_1w_1+L_2w_2$ as in the second paragraph. But you can always assume that $F$ is of that form for arbitrary real-valued functions $L_1$ and $L_2$, because $\langle w_1,w_2 \rangle$ is a basis of $W$.

@FrançoisGatine Yes, I see that much, though I'm not sure what you are hinting at. I have observed that if I can prove that the functions $a_m, b_m, c_m$ in $\mu_i(F(x_1 \textbf v_1+x_2 \textbf v_2)) = a_1(x_2)x_1^2 + b_1(x_2)x_1 + c_1(x_2) = a_2(x_1)x_2^2 + b_2(x_1)x_2 + c_2(x_1)$ take the form (for $m=1$) $a_1(x_2) = k_{1,1}, b_1(x_2) = k_{1,2}x_2, c_1(x_2) = k_{1,3}x_2^2$ ($k_{i, j} \in \mathbb R$), and similarly for $m=2$ (whence $a_1(x_2)x_1^2=c_2(x_1)$, etc.), then I am done.
